# Use JS that is already loaded, on HTML loaded via jQuery's load() function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, load

Not sure if this is posible or not, but I'm trying to use JavaScript that I loaded via a `script` tag when the page was initially requested on dynamic HTML that was loaded via jQuery's `load()` function.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/3MR43/

As you can see in the example, after clicking a link in the pop up box, the link goes. The problem is that the link was suppose to be stopped, and you were suppose to see an alert.

However, if I paste the HTML that I am loading via jQuery, it works, so the code is fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Description

You need jQuery `.live()` or `.on()` method to bind events to dynamically created html.

Choose `.live()` or `.on()` depending on the version of jQuery you are using.

> **.live()** Available since jQuery 1.3. Attach an event handler for all elements which match the current selector, now and in the future.
>
> **.on()** Available since jQuery 1.7. Attach an event handler function for one or more events to the selected elements.

Check out my sample and this [jsFiddle Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/3MR43/5/)

#### Sample

**... for jQuery.live()**

```
$('.lang').live("click", function(e) {   
    e.preventDefault();  
    alert('Testing..');        
});
```

**... for jQuery.on()**

```
$('.lang').on("click", function(e) {   
    e.preventDefault();  
    alert('Testing..');        
});
```

#### More Information

- [jsFiddle Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/3MR43/5/)
- [jQuery.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/)
- [jQuery.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your `.click` will do it for only elements that exist *at that time*. If you want to do it for all potential future elements that that selector will match, you want to use [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) (`delgate()` or `live()` with older versions of jQuery).

Answer (score 0):

The `$('.lang').click()` event must be registered after the element is created!

You need a callback on the load function to register this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use live to attach handlers to elements that are loaded dynamically.

Try this, it will solve your problem.

$('.lang').live('click',function(e) {

```
    e.preventDefault();

    alert('Testing..');

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `on` function for dynamicly loaded elements:

```
    $('.open_lang').click(function(e) {      
    e.preventDefault();    
    $('#popup').load('http://skins.thehabbos.org/pop_up/language.php').css('display', 'block');            
});

$('body').on('click', '.lang', function(e) {    
    e.preventDefault();  
    alert('Testing..');        
});
```

(`live` and `delegate` are deprecated in JQuery 1.7+ which is the version of your JSFiddle)

Fixed [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gdoron/3MR43/6/)